# spark scala typesafe config safe iterate over value of a specific column name

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, typesafe

I have found similar post on Stackoverflow. However, I could not solve my issue So, this is why I write this post.

**Aim**

The aim is to perform a column projection [projection = filter columns] while loading a SQL table (I use SQL Server).

According to the scala cookbook this is the way to filter colums [using an Array]:

```
sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,"person",Array("gender='M'"),prop)
```

However, I do not want to hardcode Array("col1", "col2", ...) inside my Scala code this is why I am using a config file with typesafe (see hereunder).

**Config file**

```
dataset {
    type = sql
    sql{
        url = "jdbc://host:port:user:name:password"
        tablename = "ClientShampooBusinesLimited"
        driver = "driver"
        other = "i have a lot of other single string elements in the config file..."
        columnList = [
        {
            colname = "id"
            colAlias = "identifient"
        }
        {
            colname = "name"
            colAlias = "nom client"
        }
        {
            colname = "age"
            colAlias = "âge client"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Let's focus on 'columnList': The name of the SQL column correspond exatecly to 'colname'. 'colAlias' is a field that I will use later.

**data.scala file**

```
lazy val columnList = configFromFile.getList("dataset.sql.columnList")
lazy val dbUrl = configFromFile.getList("dataset.sql.url")
lazy val DbTableName= configFromFile.getList("dataset.sql.tablename")
lazy val DriverName= configFromFile.getList("dataset.sql.driver")
```

configFromFile is created by myself in another custom class. But this does not matter. The type of columnList is "ConfigList" this type comes from typesafe.

**main file**

```
def loadDataSQL(): DataFrame = {

val url = datasetConfig.dbUrl 
val dbTablename = datasetConfig.DbTableName
val dbDriver = datasetConfig.DriverName
val columns = // I need help to solve this


/* EDIT 2 march 2017
   This code should not be used. Have a look at the accepted answer.
*/
sparkSession.read.format("jdbc").options(
    Map("url" -> url,
    "dbtable" -> dbTablename,
    "predicates" -> columns,
    "driver" -> dbDriver))
    .load()
}
```

So all my issue is to extract the 'colnames' values in order to put them in a suitable array. Can someone help me to write the right operhand of 'val columns' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to read the list of `colname` values into a Scala Array - I think this does it:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val columnList = configFromFile.getConfigList("dataset.sql.columnList")
val colNames: Array[String] = columnList.asScala.map(_.getString("colname")).toArray
```

With the supplied file this would result in `Array(id, name, age)`

**EDIT**: 
As to your actual goal, I actually don't know of any option named `predication` (nor can I find evidence for one in the sources, using Spark 2.0.2).

JDBC Data Source performs "projection pushdown" based on the actual columns selected in the query used. In other words - only *selected* columns would be read from DB, so you can use the `colNames` array in a `select` immediately following the DF creation, e.g.:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

sparkSession.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .options(Map("url" -> url, "dbtable" -> dbTablename, "driver" -> dbDriver))
  .load()
  .select(colNames.map(col): _*) // selecting only desired columns
```

Comment: Dear Tzach Zohar, this is exactely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: However, I get an error in     "predication" -> columns,   it says 'overloaded' method. Do you know what is the issue? Thanks

Comment: Not sure about the error you're referring to, but I updated my answer hoping to help with your actual goal of reading only selected columns from DB

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for the confusion it was not 'predication' but 'predicates'. I will edit the post. However, the solution you provided me is very nice. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot for giving infos about the 'projection pushdown'. I was reluctant at a first glance because I was thinking it would first load all colums then do a projection afterwards. However, now I got the concept of 'projection pushdown'. Regards.